# Unable to manually change the size of treatments in an ordination plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, size

I'm working with an bacterial OTU table, trying to make a PCoA using an ordination plot in R and I'd like to manually change the size of each treatment point on the plot. My data is ASV counts and organized by taxonomy in 10 treatments.

I'm able to manually change the color and shape of each treatment but not size. I'd like to use the command scale_size_manual but if I try to define the size I get an "unused argument" error.

```
ordi.abg = plot_ordination(physeq.2, sb.ord.abg, type = 'samples', color = 'Treatment', shape = 'Treatment', size = 'Treatment')
ordi.abg
```

Error in plot_ordination(physeq.2, sb.ord.abg, type = "samples", color = "Treatment",  :
unused argument (size = "Treatment")

I'm able to manually change color and shape with the following code.

```
ordi.abg  + geom_point(size=5) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  ggtitle('Soybean 20oz / CWT ') +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 7),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 5)) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("#003366", "#666699" , "#6666CC", "#6666FF", "#336699", "#330000",    "#990000", "#CC0000", "#FF0000", "#660000")) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)) +
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data. If possible the first 10 rows of your `ordi.abg`: The output of `dput(head(ordi.abg, 10))` would do

Comment: Sure! Also, I've included information on the contents of the physeq.2 file, if that's helpful.

phyloseq-class experiment-level object
otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 12893 taxa and 40 samples ]
sample_data() Sample Data:       [ 40 samples by 3 sample variables ]
tax_table()   Taxonomy Table:    [ 12893 taxa by 7 taxonomic ranks ]

Comment: @ThomasK81

list(data = structure(list(Axis.1 = c(-0.143258391752238, -0.159881140145642), Axis.2 = c(-0.28092019967889, 
-0.276127018009763), Treatment = c("T0", "T0", "T0", "T0"), Rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,), Rate = c("T", "T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X0_17", 
"X0_18")), layers = list(
    <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
    colour = ~Treatment, shape = NULL, na.rm = TRUE, x = ~Axis.1, 
    y = ~Axis.2), class = "uneval") theme = list(), coordinates = <environment>, 
    facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>,

Comment: @ThomasK81

labels = list(
        y = "Axis.2   [12.8%]", x = "Axis.1   [26.9%]", colour = "Treatment", 
        shape = "shape", na.rm = "na.rm"))